# Parametric query and hstore in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

I have a query with one parameter and am using jmoiron/sqlx to run it against Nominatim database that has a hstore field "name". The query itself is like

```
SELECT place_id, parent_place_id, name->'name:ru' as name from placesx WHERE admin_level = 3 and parent_place_id IN (?)
```

The problem when I use sqlx.In, sqlx.Bind and sqlx.Prepare functions that it takes :ru as a query parameter and complains about it.

Question is - how it can be avoided so that I can retrieve specific locale value ('name:en', 'name:de' etc) from hstore without this collision?

So far I use a regular expression and do not unmasrhal string to hstore’ map[string]string since I couldn’t figure out how to retrieve value from it by key.

Comment: Have you tried `name->'name:ru'` instead of `name->’name:ru’`?

Comment: Add  your code that you tried

Comment: It's the problem of iPad that adds those characters. I've updated the question from the PC.